Will ITA Airways flights give points for SAS Eurobonus program?
I am member of the SAS EUROBONUS program where I have gold status. SAS changed from Star Alliance to Sky Team recently. As ITA Airways is also member of Sky Team I booked several (long) trips with them, assuming that I would be able to use my gold benefits and to collect points. Later, I realized that oddly (and differently from the Star Alliance system where you always collect points from flights in partner airlines) it is not possible to use my EUROBONUS gold benefits nor collect points for EUROBONUS when flying with ITA Airways, in spite of both SAS and ITA Airways being members of Sky Team. Do you know if this situation will change and in the future it will be possible to collect points in EUROBONUS from ITA Airways flights? I am quite disappointed that I have booked all those flights with ITA Airways because the benefits I thought I would get, as them being also Sky Team was, one of the reasons to do so. I feel pretty much fooled.

I understand your frustration but this feels more like  a rant than a question. The only question I can see in here is "will this change in the future?" which I don't think anyone here can answer. To be fair, SAS is clear about who there EUROBONUS partners are: https://www.flysas.com/en/eurobonus/partners/ and that list doesn't include ITA. Same for ITA: https://www.loyaltyprogram.ita-airways.com/en_gb/airline/

I suspect that the lack of reciprocity may have something to do with ITA's impending switch to Star Alliance.

SAS tell us (in the FAQ at the bottom):

Which airlines will I be able to earn points on from 1 September 2024?
The list of airlines on which you can earn EuroBonus points is available on our SAS EuroBonus partners pages
For technical reasons, it may not be possible to automatically earn points on all SkyTeam partners on 1 September 2024, but you’ll be able to claim missing points for flights departing from 1 September once the technical solution is in place.

So it’s a temporary technical issue related to the transition, but there will be a way to claim the points back a bit later. No timeline is provided, though.
